# How to align label to top?

Tags: css

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xp2yM/)

Without modifying the html, how can I align it's label to top like in the picture:

```
<div class="col">
<label for="foo">Select:</label>
<select id="foo" name="select">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col">
<label for="bar">Select any of the following:</label>
<select id="bar" name="select">
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="22">22</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I can align label to the top and select to the bottom if it was in two div blocks using vertical-align, but I wanted to know without modifying the html code how can I align the label to the top and select to the bottom?

[image]

Comment: Where is your current CSS?

Comment: you can check this http://jsfiddle.net/xp2yM/

Comment: I have used `min-height` for label, please check if this can help. http://jsfiddle.net/xp2yM/1/

Comment: this works but not good solution, you may answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Display: Table-cell to make both columns have the same height:

```
div.col {
  display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 300%;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 40px; /* Space for the 'select'*/
}

select {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Demo: (Tested in Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/cM6Yp/

Comment: Wow, I didn't thought about absolute positioning, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it works for all your targeted browsers.